# How to Plot Every Column in Descending Order in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I intend to plot every categorical column in the dataframe in a descending order depends on the frequency of levels in a variable.

I have already found out how to plot every column and reorder the levels, but I cannot figure out how to combine them together. Could you please give me some suggestions?

Code for plot every column:

```
require(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


diamonds %>% 
  keep(is.factor) %>%
  gather() %>%
  ggplot(aes(value)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_bar()
```

Code for reorder the levels of one variable:

```
tb <- table(x)
factor(x, levels = names(tb[order(tb, decreasing = TRUE)]))
```

BTW, if you feel there is a better way writing these codes, please let me know. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible data (bank_add in this case) for your question?

Comment: (1) you have one too many `r`s in your code. (2) What is `bank_add`? (And please don't respond with just "it's my data", since that doesn't help me understand anything, including number 3 here.) (3) What does "descending order" mean when talking about whole columns of data? Is it descending `sum`s, `min`s, `max`s, `mean`s, `cor`s, `t.test`s, or something else? (If you make this question a little more [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), we might be able to give you more salient help.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I made some changes. Now I am using diamonds data from ggplot2 package. Also "descending order" means the frequency of levels in a categorical variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Alternative 1**

No need to use `gridExtra` to emulate `facet_wrap`, just include the function `reorder_size` inside `aes`:

```
reorder_size <- function(x) {
  factor(x, levels = names(sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)))
}

diamonds %>% 
  keep(is.factor) %>%
  gather() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder_size(value))) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_bar()
```

**Alternative 2**

Using `dplyr`to calculate the count grouping by key and value. Then we `reorder` the value in descending order by count inside `aes`.

```
library(dplyr)
diamonds %>% 
  keep(is.factor) %>%
  gather() %>%
  group_by(key,value) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(value, -n), y = n)) +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free") +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

**Output**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that the long form of your data-frame will introduce a lot of factors that would be plotted as 0 for the geom_bar().

Instead of relying on facet_wrap and dealing with the long data-form, here's an alternative.

Reordering by size function:

```
reorder_size <- function(x) {
  factor(x, levels = names(sort(table(x), decreasing=T)))
}
```

Using `gridExtra::grid.arrange` function to deliver similar facet_wrap style figure:

```
library(gridExtra)
a <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=reorder_size(cut))) + geom_bar()
b <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=reorder_size(color))) + geom_bar()
c <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=reorder_size(clarity))) + geom_bar()
grid.arrange(a,b,c, nrow=1)
```

[image]