# Plot the levels of a variable grouped by another variable in ascending order in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to arrange the bar graphs in ascending order by the levels of a variable. The other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001024/ggplot-order-bars-in-faceted-bar-chart-per-facet) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43359586/how-to-plot-every-column-in-descending-order-in-r) do not work.

Here is an example data

```
x <- c(rep(letters[1:2], each = 6))
y <- c(rep(letters[3:8], times = 2))
z <- c(2, 4, 7, 5, 11, 8, 9, 2, 3, 4, 10, 11)
dat <- data.frame(x,y,z)
```

What I want to achieve is to plot a bar graph of the levels of `y` grouped by `x` in increasing order.

The following arranges `y` in increasing order.

```
library(tidyverse)    
dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(y) %>%
  arrange(x, z) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(y = reorder(y, z))
dat2
```

However, the resulting plots are not what I was expecting.

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(y,z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~x, scales = "free")
```

How can I arrange the levels of `y` in increasing order of `z` by `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect the bars to be increasing within each facet, the same value of `y` needs to be in a different position for different facets. Try this instead:

```
dat3 <- dat %>%
  mutate(x.y = paste(x, y, sep = ".")) %>%
  mutate(x.y = factor(x.y, levels = x.y[order(z)]))
# this creates a new variable that combines x & y; different facets
# simply use different subsets of values from this variable

ggplot(dat3, aes(x.y,z)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "y", breaks = dat3$x.y, labels = dat3$y) +
  facet_wrap(~x, scales = "free")
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Wow. Now that I see it, it makes a lot of sense. Such a neat trick. Thank you!